# Clean way to filter a list by multiple numbers

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a JSON file like below. What is the cleanest way to filter the list by age so that I can also filter for multiple ages. I do not want to use an or operator, because this will be a very long logical operation in a larger filter example.

```
// DON'T
return this.users.filter((user) => {
  return user.age=== 17 || user.age=== 20 || ....
});
```

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Nick",
  "age": 17
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 20
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Ray",
  "age": 19
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.includes` for this purpose:

```
return this.users.filter(user => [17, 20, 22, 26, 35, 36, 80].includes(user.age));
```

Comment: I would suggest using a `Set` with `Set#has` that would be O(1).

Comment: @AZ_ Readability & simplicity >>> performance in checks like this.

Comment: `let set = new Set( [17, 20, 22, 26, 35, 36, 80]);` `users.filter(user => set.has(user.age));` i find it equally readible.

Answer (score 1):

```
let ages = [17, 20, 30, ... ]
return this.users.filter((user) => {
  return ages.indexOf(user.age) > -1 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data using `Array.prototype.includes`, create an array for the `allowedAges` then filter based on `allowedAges.inclues(user.age)`

Example,

```js
const userData = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Nick",
  "age": 17
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 20
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Ray",
  "age": 19
}]

const allowedAges = [17,20]

const filteredData = userData.filter(user => allowedAges.includes(user.age));

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: I gave this answer 3 minutes ago already.